# Values of type 'collection[Edm.String(Nullable=True,DefaultValue=,MaxLength=,Unicode=,FixedLength=)]' can not be converted to string

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am try to join two table **Products** and **ProductImages** and storing the result into another class **ProductDisplay** which will store  multiple product  **Id**,**Name**, and first **ImageId**,**ImageName**.

If there is no Image in the **ProductImages** table **ProductDisplay** will contain **NoId** and **NoProductImage** in the list.

But this Linq throwing an exception

```
  var products = (from p in db.Products
                   select new ProductDisplay
                   {
                       ProductId = p.Id,
                       Name = p.Name,
                       Image = (from ppi in db.ProductImages
                                       where ppi.ProductId == p.Id
                                       select ppi.Image == null ? "noproductimage.jpg" : ppi.Image).ToString(),
                        ProductImageId = (from ppi in db.ProductImages
                                         where ppi.ProductId == p.Id
                                         select ppi.Id.ToString() == null ? "NoId" : ppi.Id.ToString()).ToString()
                   }).ToList();
```

I think this below code throwing the exception

```
      select ppi.Id.ToString() == null ? "NoId" : ppi.Id.ToString()).ToString()
```

help please...

Comment: Try `...select ppi.Id == null ? "NoId" : ppi.Id.ToString())`

Comment: Is ProductImages.Id defined as nullable?  Not a good idea for a key field.  Non-nullable value would never == null.

Comment: I got it. Thank you @JohnWhite 


Yes it was. I used **.FirstOrDefault()** which solve the exception issue

Comment: ppi.Id == null always return **false** thats why I had to convert to **.ToString()** @SteveGreene

Comment: You can't call `ToString()` on a null value.

Answer (score 0):

You have entity-framework tagged so why aren't you just:

```
var myList = db.Products.Include("ProductImages").ToList();
```

and then select from myList using a mapping technique.  Are there multiple images per Product?

Comment: Yes there was multiple images per Product.And that's why I had to use that **IQueryable** technique and I solved it.

Comment: Ok, last suggestion (for future maintenance).  Separate data retrieval from data formatting/mapping.  Then, each can change independently from the other as needs and sources change.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer but unable to add "noproductimage.jpg" and "NoId". But my code will works with NULL and 0 respectively for **"noproductimage.jpg"** and **"NoId"**.

```
    var product = from p in db.Products
                select new 
                {
                    ProductId = p.Id,
                    Name = p.Name,
                    Image = (from ppi in db.ProductImages
                             where ppi.ProductId == p.Id
                             select ppi.Image).FirstOrDefault(),
                    ProductImageId = (from ppi in db.ProductImages
                                      where ppi.ProductId == p.Id
                                      select ppi.Id).FirstOrDefault()
                };
```